# How do I add an extra separator to the top of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a view for the iPhone that is basically split in two, with an informational display in the top half, and a UITableView for selecting actions in the bottom half.  The problem is that there is no border or separator above the first cell in the UITableView, so the first item in the list looks funny.  How can I add an extra separator at the top of the table, to separate it from the display area above it?

Here's the code to build the cells - it's pretty straightforward.  The overall layout is handled in a xib.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Action 1";
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Action 2";
            break;
        }
        // etc.......
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 70):

To replicate the standard iOS separator lines, I use a 1 px (not 1 pt) hair line `tableHeaderView` with the table view's `separatorColor`:

```
// in -viewDidLoad
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] 
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                    self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
    line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
    line;
});
```

The same in Swift (thanks, Dane Jordan, Yuichi Kato, Tony Merritt):

```
let px = 1 / UIScreen.main.scale
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: px)
let line = UIView(frame: frame)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = line
line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor
```

Comment: whats it called using the ({ object }); notation?

Comment: This is called a statement expression (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). Of course you could also write it without it but it nicely scopes the definition of the UIView.

Comment: Yeah especially when there are a lot of things happening in the viewdidload. Thanks for this!

Comment: For swift users:


`var px = 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, px)
        var line: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = line
        line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor`

Comment: For Swift 3.0 users
 let px = 1 / UIScreen.main.scale
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: px)
        let line: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = line
        line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor

Comment: Still can be used swift 3 and 4... `let px = 1 / UIScreen.main.scale
  let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: px)
  let line = UIView(frame: frame)
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = line
  line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor`

Answer (score 14):

I just got hit with this same problem and realised that the separator at the top is only displayed whilst scrolling the table.

What I then did was the following

1. In Interface Builder go to "Scroll View Size"
2. Set the Content Insets of Top to 1

Alternatively in code you could do

```
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

NOTE: This no longer works for iOS7 as the separators are no longer shown at all.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and could not find an answer.  So I added a line to the bottom of my table header.

```
CGRect  tableFrame = [[self view] bounds] ; 
CGFloat headerHeight = 100;        
UIView * headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableFrame.size.width, headerHeight)];
// Add stuff to my table header...

// Create separator
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, headerHeight-1, tableFrame.size.width, 1)] ;
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:224/255.0 green:224/255.0 blue:224/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[headerView addSubview:lineView];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

```
extension UITableView {
    func addTableHeaderViewLine() {
        self.tableHeaderView = {
            let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale))
            line.backgroundColor = self.separatorColor
            return line
        }()
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't using the frame width cause a problem if the user changes orientation while the table is visible?

Answer (score 5):

I made a UITableView extension that displays a native style separator on top of the UITableView, while the table gets scrolled.

[image: Here is how it looks]

Here's the code

```
fileprivate var _topSeparatorTag = 5432 // choose unused tag

extension UITableView {

    fileprivate var _topSeparator: UIView? {
        return superview?.subviews.filter { $0.tag == _topSeparatorTag }.first
    }
    
    override open var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        didSet {
            guard let topSeparator = _topSeparator else { return }
            
            let shouldDisplaySeparator = contentOffset.y > 0
            
            if shouldDisplaySeparator && topSeparator.alpha == 0 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
                    topSeparator.alpha = 1
                })
            } else if !shouldDisplaySeparator && topSeparator.alpha == 1 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    topSeparator.alpha = 0
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Adds a separator to the superview at the top of the table
    // This needs the separator insets to be set on the tableView, not the cell itself
    func showTopSeparatorWhenScrolled(_ enabled: Bool) {
        if enabled {
            if _topSeparator == nil {
                let topSeparator = UIView()
                topSeparator.backgroundColor = separatorColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.85) // because while scrolling, the other separators seem lighter
                topSeparator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                superview?.addSubview(topSeparator)

                topSeparator.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: separatorInset.left).isActive = true
                topSeparator.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: separatorInset.right).isActive = true
                topSeparator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
                let onePixelInPoints = CGFloat(1) / UIScreen.main.scale 
                topSeparator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: onePixelInPoints).isActive = true
                
                topSeparator.tag = _topSeparatorTag
                topSeparator.alpha = 0

                superview?.setNeedsLayout()
            }
        } else {
            _topSeparator?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    func removeSeparatorsOfEmptyCells() {
        tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

To enable it, simply call `tableView.showTopSeparatorWhenScrolled(true)` after you set your `delegate` for your `UITableView`

Comment: What is LayoutHelper?

Comment: Sorry this is my own class. I replaced this method call with generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

In complement of [Ortwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28177407/5461998), if you need to add some margin to your top separator to fit the separator inset, you have to embedded your top separator in another view :

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
UIView *topSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.separatorInset.left, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width - self.tableView.separatorInset.left - self.tableView.separatorInset.right, 1 / UIScreen.mainScreen.scale)];
topSeparator.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
[headerView addSubview:topSeparator];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding one extra line at the beginning of the table. Just have to set its height to 1, set its the text to empty, disable user interaction for it and in the whole code adjust the indexPath.row value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a separator between header view and first row :-
In view for Header in section delegate method add a subview self.separator
//@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *separator;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 41; 
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIUtils colorForRGBColor:TIMESHEET_HEADERVIEW_COLOR];

self.separator = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperator.png"]];
self.separator.frame = CGRectMake(0,40,self.view.frame.size.width,1);
[self.headerView addSubview:self.separator];
return self.headerView;

}
```