# How to change UITableView section borders?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UITableView and I simply want to set the same width to all separators. I already know something about customizing uitableview, but this one is a mystery to me.[image: Here is what I have]. 
Basically, I want to set this section headers separators to be the same width as cell separators, have the same leading space to the superview. What's the best way to do it?

**EDIT**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = header.textLabel?.font.withSize(12)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = ColorConstants.symbolsColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers and footers don't have separator lines but you can mock them using custom UIViews and putting them in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    let px = 1 / UIScreen.main.scale
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: px)
    let line = UIView(frame: frame)
    view.addSubview(line)
    line.backgroundColor = self.tableView.separatorColor
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view
}
```

And add your other code to this function as well instead of willDisplayHeaderView.
You may need to adjust the CGRect dimensions to match what you want exactly. I believe the default cell separators start at 15 points (not 100% sure on that)

credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28177407/7535093

Comment: I want to keep cell separator inset as it is. Instead, I want to change that other separator, which goes from edge to edge. Is that a section border or smth?

Comment: Are you using custom views for your headers or just titles?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: It just added this custom view above the default header :(

Comment: Did you delete or comment out the original code you had?

Comment: I commented it out

Comment: I've just found out, that if I set separatorStyle to .none, all the lines in the tableview disappear. I guess, now I need to create custom cells with shadow dropping with x-offset

Answer (score 0):

In the table view method CellForRowAt...
Try adding this code

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false 
cell.seperatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't change anything